# What is the "correct" way to store a contact's ID in android

Tags: android

I've got an app in the market which stores details against contacts by using a contact picker. When I've returned from the contact picker I had been using the following to obtain the contact:

```
cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID)
```

I've found that using this is ok until somebody flashes a new rom or gets a new phone and then all the ID's have changed.

I've looked at the android documentation and I've seen references to using ContactsContract.Contacts.LOOKUP_KEY, but the description confuses me "An opaque value that contains hints on how to find the contact if its row id changed as a result of a sync or aggregation."

So what should I be using to store the contact ID?

Comment: a local database perhaps for your app? and backup it before flashing?

Comment: Store `LOOKUP_KEY` & remember to read (& implement) a [backup agent](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/backup.html) - unless you actually *feel* like maintaining a server for the backups yourself in perpetuity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lookup Key is the correct reference for contacts.

[Contacts Provider / Contacts:](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/contacts-provider.html#ContactBasics)

> The ContactsContract.Contacts table also has the column LOOKUP_KEY
>   that is a "permanent" link to the contact row. Because the Contacts
>   Provider maintains contacts automatically, it may change a contact
>   row's _ID value in response to an aggregation or sync. Even If this
>   happens, the content URI CONTENT_LOOKUP_URI combined with contact's
>   LOOKUP_KEY will still point to the contact row, so you can use
>   LOOKUP_KEY to maintain links to "favorite" contacts, and so forth.
>   This column has its own format that is unrelated to the format of the
>   _ID column.